# Change draggable items or how to remove draggable data in right way

Tags: jquery, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

I need to allow some ojects to be draggable, but every time it's a different set of objects.
How can I remove draggable data from the previous set?

P.S. `$('.draggable').draggable('destroy');` returns an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined`

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: @Juhana it's `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable( "disable" );
```

http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#method-disable

~KP

Comment: but when I enable it again, the old items will be draggable again. I need to do it a few times with different sets

Comment: different sets - can you keep different class for each set.

Comment: I don't know how many sets I'll have, but it's definitely more than 30, too much to give them different classes, I need to replace 'destroy' method somehow